# Firebase Auth object saved on local storage doesn't get updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am signing up using email and then updating the phone number using NODE ADMIN API from my backened. The firebase console shows the phone number is been added but the Android App doesnt reflect the changes. Only after I SIGNOUT and SIGNIN , it shows the phone number in my auth object.

Is there any workaround for this? Or any way to directly add phone number without going with the signing flow of phone auth credential?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, have you fix it ? I currently have the same issue, I'm thinking on manage my own "phone number" field in my database instead of listening for FirebaseAuth. I'll apreciate your comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use on child added listener or if you added the phone number from the first time use on child changed listener

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the Android client of the change and then `reload()` the user. You may also force token refresh if you need the phone number to also propagate to the user's ID token.